# how to apply condition on all frames?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to apply this condition on all frame of adobe flash cs 6:

```
if(pauseMusic.visible==true) {
    playMusic.visible=false;
} else if(pauseMusic.visible==false) {
    playMusic.visible=true;
}
```

But I don't want to copy it one by one of frame actions. What cant I do?

Comment: make it as a movie clip and paste it in one frame

Comment: This is not an answer but for Boolean you may avoid if... else... Try
playMusic.visible = ! playMusic.visible; This is shorter shorter...

Comment: Thank you a lot to reject this stupid edit I made.
Don't know who You are but, it was a big mistake to edit the question!
Best regards.
Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function in first frame:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameEnter);
    function onFrameEnter(Event):void
    {
        if(pauseMusic.visible==true)
        {
            playMusic.visible=false;
        }
        else if(pauseMusic.visible==false)
        {
            playMusic.visible=true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: pauseMusic.visible = !pauseMusic.visible;

This is shorter and You avoid the if... else (too long and useless). AMO

Answer (score 1):

!
create a function in your first frame
if you have more than one frame in your time line, at the first frame insert it:

```
if(this._condition == null) {
  this._condition = function():void {
    if(pauseMusic.visible==true) {
        playMusic.visible=false;
    } else if(pauseMusic.visible==false) {
        playMusic.visible=true;
    }
  }
}
```

and simply call it in other frames : `this._condition();`

Comment: Thank you but by using this function when back to previous frame the buttons not visible...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @payamsbr but this is shorter...

```
    _condition = function():void {
        pauseMusic.visible = !pauseMusic.visible;
    }
```

So you may avoid the if... else... check.
The initial Boolean should be defined to

> true or false

So all You have to do is to call

```
_condition();
```

[EDIT]

OR in case of uint 1 ->-1 or -1 to 1:

```
var i:uint=1
function changeUint():void{
    i = *=-1
}

changeUint();

-> 1 to -1 or -1 to 1
```

> 1 to -1 or -1 to 1...

[/EDIT]

But You want to check if the function exist as he said.